# MySQL Remote connection not succeeding

Tags: debian, mysql, remote

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL db remotely for about 10 hours with no luck.

The server is running Debian.

The `my.cnf` is configured correctly with `bind-ip 0.0.0.0` and no skip-networking.

`lsof -i :3306` shows an established connection from the connecting IP to the server, but then dies off.

When using tcpdump port 3306 and '(tcp-syn|tcp-ack)!=0' on server I get this when trying to connect to it:

10:55:44.195273 IP server2.xxx.xxx.mysql > xxx.xxx.12.89.53920: Flags [R], seq 1740903883, win 0, length 0

The user connecting is granted all access from `%`.

I don't know what more to do. The server is running `ISPConfig` with `bastille` firewall but even with it off nothing works. I am able to connect to the db locally and LAN addresses.

This is what I get when I'm trying to connect to the db server:

"ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 2 "No such file or directory"

my.cnf

skip_name_resolve is on

bind address commented

Any clues?

Comment: From a remote host, are you able to `nc -z -w 2 dbhost.example.com 3306` successfully?

Comment: The command executes without any return with the correct address.

Comment: With what exit code?

Comment: No exit code at all

Comment: Not possible.  All programs return an exit code upon exit.  Re-run the command, and follow it up with `echo $?`.

Comment: What is your definition of "remotely"? local lan or another location?

Comment: run `tcpdump -l -n host dbhost.example.com and port 3306` on the remote host, and `tcpdump -l -n host remote.host.com and port 3306` on the database server, then attempt to connect. If there's a discrepancy, check the firewall.

Comment: Return value is 0. Remotely is from external IP to server.

Comment: what happens if you add 'skip-name-resolve' to the configuration? (doing that also means the grant has to use an IP address and not a DNS name)

Comment: I'm running with that already unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

TCP networking is clearly working: you get a connection, and alternative connection tools such as `nc` also demonstrate this.

It is either MySQL blocking the incoming connection itself (likely) or your version has been compiled with TCP Wrappers and that is set to require Reverse DNS and maybe even forward/reverse matching.

The MySQL documentation [B.5.2.5 Host 'host_name' is blocked](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blocked-host.html) explains that too many incomplete connections will cause the originating IP address to be blocked until `mysqladm flush-hosts` is run. Or you can login and execute `FLUSH HOSTS`.

To check the TCP Wrappers configuration you need to look at `/etc.hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny`.

Comment: I ran mysqladmin flush-hosts with exit value 0 on host and then tried to connect. No change.

Content of hosts.allow
ALL:ALL

Content of hosts.deny
Empty

Comment: How do I check if compiled with TCP Wrappers?

Comment: lsof -i :3306 shows *:mysql LISTEN on server.

Comment: When using  tcpdump port 3306 and '(tcp-syn|tcp-ack)!=0' on server I get this when trying to connect to it: 10:55:44.195273 IP server2.xxx.xxx.mysql > xxx.xxx.12.89.53920: Flags [R], seq 1740903883, win 0, length 0

Comment: I get this when trying to connect to db server: "ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 2 "No such file or directory"

Comment: @AndreasWinkler please add this new information to your question. It's too important to hide in comments.